# How do I run two separate files on different ports with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

There are two entry points.
**main.js
index.js**
and there are two html files

main.html
index.html

When building, I have js files connected to Html. index.js is linked to index.html and the like.

The task is to create two commands in the package.json file
**start-index** - `starts index.html file on port 3000`
**start-main** `runs main.html file on port 8080`

Each of them must run different Html with different connected files on different ports.

Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, something like this may be helpful - I'm not sure why you would need two js files, you can probably just a framework like express, and just serve different files on different ports. Let me know if this is what you're looking for!

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
    
const app = express();
const secondaryApp = express();

const PRIMARY_PORT = process.env.PRIMARY_PORT || 3000; 
const SECONDARY_PORT = process.env.SECONDARY_PORT || 8000;

const STATIC = path.join(__dirname, '../static/');
const HTML_FILE_PRIMARY = path.join(STATIC, 'index.html');
const HTML_FILE_SECONDARY = path.join(STATIC, 'index2.html');

app.use(express.static(STATIC));
secondaryApp.use(express.static(STATIC));

// Add routes to both apps
app.post('/route', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).end();
});

secondaryApp.post('/route', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).end();
});

// Set up both GET requests to index
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(HTML_FILE_PRIMARY);
})

secondaryApp.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(HTML_FILE_SECONDARY);
})

// Let both servers listen on their own ports
app.listen(PRIMARY_PORT, () => {
    console.log("Primary app listening on port: "+PRIMARY_PORT);
})

secondaryApp.listen(SECONDARY_PORT, () => {
    console.log("Secondary app listening on port: "+SECONDARY_PORT);
});
```